# Electron 14: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')

Tags: javascript, electron

As the title says, I am getting this error again and again whenever I am trying to change the browserwindow: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')`

According to my previous question, I had a problem with the import/export. Now that I found about ipcRenderer, I used it but still got an error:

Here is my main.js (index.js)

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcRenderer } = require("electron")

var mainWindow = null

app.on("ready", () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500,
        "webPreferences": {
            "contextIsolation": false,
            "nodeIntegration": true,
        },
        "opacity": 0.7,
    })

    mainWindow.loadFile("src/html/welcome.html")
})

ipcRenderer.on("update", (event, args) => {
    mainWindow.loadFile("src/html/update.html")
})
```

And let's say this is my any js file:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron")

ipcRenderer.send("update")
```

After running the above code, I get an error. Now I comment out the ipcRenderer.on() line, the app works as expected.

Comment: I even tried creating a new window but still got an error

Comment: `ipcRenderer` is not available in the main process. Use `ipcMain` when handling events.

Comment: Should i just replace ipcRenderer with ipcMain?

Comment: At least in the main process, yes. Not in the renderer process, because it's correct there. (If you're wondering: The renderer process runs all code which runs inside your `BrowserWindow` but please refer to Electron's documentation!)

Comment: Oh i see! I was just now looking that the documentation of ipcMain.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner, Thanks, it works! You can just add in answer so that I can accept.